# How to deal with dependency conflicts using custom classloader in java properly?

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader, agent, byte-buddy

I have a multimodule project called `k-sdk`. It has modules like

**--->** `agent`

**--->** `core`

**--->** `api`

**--->** `integration`

**--->** `sdk`

where (**sdk** module contains **core**, **api**, **integration** modules and acting as a shaded jar).
This jar can be imported as a dependency in the user application.

Here `k-sdk` is acting as a middleware to capture `request` and `response` of the api calls (both external and internal) and do some custom processing. And to intercept the internal calls i am using `servlet-filter` & for external calls, i am using [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) and wrote the required code in the `premain` method. The corresponding interceptors are written in **integration** module. User can use this `k-sdk` by running agent jar(present in agent module) of the `k-sdk`.

Now comes to the actual problem. Suppose I have written an Interceptor for `OkHttp` client version `4.10.0` in the `integration` module and the user is using the same client of version `3.14.9`, now these two versions share completely same package name. And there are some uncommon apis, methods etc, which is being used in the `OkHttpInterceptor` which results in **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** because maven only resolves that version of dependency which has the shortest path. And only 1 version of a dependency will be loaded in the classloader.

Now, To resolve this version conflict what i was thinking that i will use the below custom classloader. ([ref](https://medium.com/@isuru89/java-a-child-first-class-loader-cbd9c3d0305)) as i know that the solution lies in this approach only.

```java
public class ChildFirstClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private final ClassLoader sysClzLoader;

    public ChildFirstClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(urls, parent);
        sysClzLoader = getSystemClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // has the class loaded already?
        Class<?> loadedClass = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (loadedClass == null) {
            try {
                if (sysClzLoader != null) {
                    loadedClass = sysClzLoader.loadClass(name);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                // class not found in system class loader... silently skipping
            }

            try {
                // find the class from given jar urls as in first constructor parameter.
                if (loadedClass == null) {
                    loadedClass = findClass(name);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // class is not found in the given urls.
                // Let's try it in parent classloader.
                // If class is still not found, then this method will throw class not found ex.
                loadedClass = super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }

        if (resolve) {      // marked to resolve
            resolveClass(loadedClass);
        }
        return loadedClass;
    }



    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        List<URL> allRes = new LinkedList<>();

        // load resources from sys class loader
        Enumeration<URL> sysResources = sysClzLoader.getResources(name);
        if (sysResources != null) {
            while (sysResources.hasMoreElements()) {
                allRes.add(sysResources.nextElement());
            }
        }

        // load resource from this classloader
        Enumeration<URL> thisRes = findResources(name);
        if (thisRes != null) {
            while (thisRes.hasMoreElements()) {
                allRes.add(thisRes.nextElement());
            }
        }

        // then try finding resources from parent classloaders
        Enumeration<URL> parentRes = super.findResources(name);
        if (parentRes != null) {
            while (parentRes.hasMoreElements()) {
                allRes.add(parentRes.nextElement());
            }
        }

        return new Enumeration<URL>() {
            Iterator<URL> it = allRes.iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public URL nextElement() {
                return it.next();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        URL res = null;
        if (sysClzLoader != null) {
            res = sysClzLoader.getResource(name);
        }
        if (res == null) {
            res = findResource(name);
        }
        if (res == null) {
            res = super.getResource(name);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

And to improve the user experience, i have to make changes only in the `premain` method. Now i don't know how to use this classloader to resolve this conflicting issue.

The above classloader is extending `URLClassLoader`, and the application class loader is no longer an instance of `java.net.URLClassLoader` in java 9+.

I am very new to this complex solution, Please! help me out.

Before this solution, i tried to repackage classes using `maven-shade-plugin` but that solution was not working because in `premain` method using ByteBuddy i was targeting a class of actual package and was using different package in the interceptor so the flow was not going to the interceptor as the class was not matching.

Comment: You are mixing up two different tasks. First, creating a runtime environment which can cope with different versions of the same library. Second, implementing a Java Agent which can work correctly in such an environment. There is no way around the second task, so if `maven-shade-plugin` did already solve the first task but your Agent did not use the correct package, try fixing your Agent.

Comment: Basically what i was thinking that i will set my custom classloader as the default and will not load the `integration` module by adding some check and when user application's flow will go to the `premain` method in `agent` module then i will get user external dependencies through getClass().getClassLoader().And then will load only those dependencies which user is using.And also i will have to make  submodules of `integration` module by different dependency versions). and will load only those modules for which interceptor is being used. For eg: okhttp 3.14.9 interceptor module. if user uses it.

Comment: You can refer this repo[https://github.com/keploy/java-sdk]. In this project i am trying to achieve the above task.