# Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main when using custom classloader

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I am trying to set my custom classloader `MyCL` to replace the default system classloader.

For this i have tried writing the below commands,where setCustomCL is my application jar file.

i)  `javac -J-Djava.class.path=/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/setCustomCL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -J-Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.ccl.MyCL`

ii) `javac -J-Djava.class.path=/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/setCustomCL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/gouravkumar/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_342/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar -J-Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.ccl.MyCL`

I am using below classloader as `MyCL`.

```java
package org.example.ccl;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCL extends ClassLoader {

    private static final String CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION = ".class";

    public MyCL(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] Constructor:" + parent);
    }

    public MyCL() {
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] Default Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Check if the class is already loaded
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] loading class: " + name);
        Class<?> clazz = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (clazz != null) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] class already loaded:" + clazz);
            return clazz;
        }

        // Delegate to the parent classloader for bootstrap and extension classes
        if (isBootstrapClass(name) || isExtensionClass(name)) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] {" + name + "} should be loaded by boostrap or extension classloader");
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }

        // Try to load the class with this classloader
        byte[] classData = loadClassData(name);
        clazz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        if (resolve) {
            resolveClass(clazz);
        }
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] succesfully loaded:" + clazz);
        return clazz;
    }

    private boolean isBootstrapClass(String name) {
        String[] bootstrapPrefixes = {
                "java.",
                "java/",
                "javax.",
                "javax/",
                "sun.",
                "sun/",
                "com.sun.",
                "com/sun/"};
        for (String prefix : bootstrapPrefixes) {
            if (name.startsWith(prefix)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isExtensionClass(String name) {
        String[] extensionPrefixes = {
                "com.sun.javafx.",
                "com.oracle.",
                "jdk.",
                "oracle.",
                "netscape.",
                "org.ietf.jgss.",
                "sunw.",
                "org.omg.",
                "org.w3c.dom.",
                "org.xml.sax.",
                "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.",
                "com.sun.xml.internal.",
                "com.sun.activation.",
                "com.sun.imageio.",
                "com.sun.jmx.",
                "com.sun.management.",
                "com.sun.org.apache.",
                "com.sun.security.",
                "com.sun.tools.",
                "jdk.internal.",
                "oracle.net.",
                "sun.awt.",
                "sun.misc.",
                "sun.net.",
                "sun.security.",
                "sun.text.",
                "sun.util."
        };
        for (String prefix : extensionPrefixes) {
            if (name.startsWith(prefix)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String className) {
        String classFileName = className.replace('.', '/') + CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION;
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] trying to get class data of class:" + classFileName);
        InputStream inputStream = getResourceAsStream(classFileName);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] cannot get class data as inputstream is null.");
            return null;
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] unable to read class data:" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] trying getResource() on:" + name);
        URL res = null;

        // Delegate to the parent classloader for bootstrap and extension classes
        if (isBootstrapClass(name) || isExtensionClass(name)) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] {" + name + "} getResource() should be fetched by boostrap or extension classloader");
            return super.getResource(name);
        }

        res = findResource(name);

        if (res == null) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] unable to getResource from current classloader");
            res = super.getResource(name);
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) {
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] trying getResources() on:" + name);

        List<URL> allRes = new LinkedList<>();
        try {

            // Delegate to the parent classloader for bootstrap and extension classes
            if (isBootstrapClass(name) || isExtensionClass(name)) {
                System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] {" + name + "}  getResources() should be fetched by boostrap or extension classloader");
                return super.getResources(name);
            }

            // load resource from this classloader
            Enumeration<URL> thisRes = findResources(name);
            if (thisRes != null) {
                while (thisRes.hasMoreElements()) {
                    allRes.add(thisRes.nextElement());
                }
            }

            // then try finding resources from parent classloaders
            Enumeration<URL> parentRes = super.findResources(name);
            if (parentRes != null) {
                while (parentRes.hasMoreElements()) {
                    allRes.add(parentRes.nextElement());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] unable to getResources() from any classloader");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] successfully executed getResources()");
        return new Enumeration<URL>() {
            final Iterator<URL> it = allRes.iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public URL nextElement() {
                return it.next();
            }
        };
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] trying getResourceAsStream() on:" + name);

        // Delegate to the parent classloader for bootstrap and extension classes
        if (isBootstrapClass(name) || isExtensionClass(name)) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] {" + name + "} getResourceAsStream() should be fetched by boostrap or extension classloader");
            return super.getResourceAsStream(name);
        }

        InputStream inputStream = getResourceAsStream(name);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            System.out.println("[MyCL classloader] successfull executed getResourceAsStream()");
            return inputStream;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
➜  java git:(main) ✗ javac -J-Djava.class.path=/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/setCustomCL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/gouravkumar/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_342/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar -J-Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.ccl.MyCL
[MyCL classloader] Constructor:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[MyCL classloader] loading class: com.sun.tools.javac.Main
[MyCL classloader] {com.sun.tools.javac.Main} should be loaded by boostrap or extension classloader
[MyCL classloader] trying getResource() on:sun/text/resources/unorm.icu
[MyCL classloader] {sun/text/resources/unorm.icu} getResource() should be fetched by boostrap or extension classloader
[MyCL classloader] loading class: com.sun.tools.javac.Main
[MyCL classloader] {com.sun.tools.javac.Main} should be loaded by boostrap or extension classloader
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you add `tools.jar` to the bootstrap path? `javac` should already know how to locate the compiler classes. And what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: I was trying to resolve my previous issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75450643/how-to-deal-with-dependency-conflicts-using-custom-classloader-in-java-properly

Comment: I don’t understand how manipulating the environment of `javac` is supposed to solve problems you get at runtime with the compiled classes. This manipulation does not even make sense for the compilation itself, as `javac` uses the paths provided with the `-classpath` option. It does not use a class loader.